# Real time monitor and block a web request

Tags: c#, sockets, networkstream, sniffer

I am planning on creating a free open source Porn blocker software that as much as possible blocks porn websites.

The idea is to create a list of websites like xxxporn.xxx or whatever and once user at any time tries to visit that website in any web browser it just kills the request and the user goes no where.

I am good with programming and my problem isn't with code i just want to know from where should i start?

I heard about packet sniffers so how do i do it in C#? all i want is just a demo method or a code sample that shows me the currently vistied websites and kill the request when a predefined website is visited.

Comment: Congrats on taking on such a big project.  You'll want to start by crawling TGP (thumbnail gallery preview) sites to get your starter lists.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a web crawler and had to deal with filtering out porn on free crawls.

Looks for the following terms:
18 U.S.C 2257
18 U.S.C. 2257
section 2257 compliance

Most pornographic sites have these terms in their html source.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your request, but rather only ones view on the subject.

Porn is not something that just Pops up while you are surfing regular web sites. like this one for example... Porn is something that you need to look for.

If you have small children and you dont want them to be exposed to things that are not under your control you can simply define all their surfing destinations with windows firewall.

If you have older children and you are afraid that they might wonder off in search for porn due to age or hormonal impulses, or get exposed by simply surfing to all sorts of dubious and pirated websites, you should have a talk with them and explain things in a grown manner and not try to block the reality of life in such medieval way.

In this modern age where internet governs all aspects of our lives, and there are far greater risks out there in cyberspace then porn, proper training and education on what is good and bad when surfing is the key to save kids from all risks and harmful contents.

I apologize that this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I agree.  You do need to look for it.  Also, my comment on how to detect it will prevent most US sites from being loaded.  It won't have much effect for international sites.